# getElementsByClassName not letting me change fontsize

Tags: javascript, font-size, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to make a JavaScript script that will change the "Resizable" Class elements on my page, however I don't think that I am using the getElementsByClassName correctly.
Here is my code:

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Resizable');
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.fontSize = parseFloat(elements[i].style.fontSize) + (multiplier+ * 0.2)
    }
}
```

I have a button using onclick="resizeText(1)" and another with (-1), neither are working and I am unsure why. Am I correct in using getElementsByClassName to make an Array and then try and change the style of each object?

Comment: What does it mean `(multiplier+ * 0.2)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Resizable');
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.fontSize = parseFloat(elements[i].style.fontSize) + (multiplier * 0.2) + 'px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

May be you're missing "px" at the end:

```
function resizeText(multiplier) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('Resizable');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.fontSize = parseFloat(elements[i].style.fontSize) + (multiplier + * 0.2) + "px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
elements[i].style.fontSize = (parseFloat(elements[i].style.fontSize) + (multiplier+ * 0.2)) + "px";
```

or the element's font-size has initial value?